# swap control and alt for all keyboard shortcuts in vscode on linux

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you remap all control keyboard shortcuts to use alt and all alt keyboard shortcuts to use control?

In firefox you can swap the `ui.key.accelKey` and the `ui.key.menuAccessKey` to swap the buttons. Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39462/how-do-i-reconfigure-keyboard-shortcuts-for-copy-and-paste).

Is there a way for this to be done in vscode without changing each one manually? I want it to work for all shortcuts like control shift p, copy, paste, control w, control t, control shift t.

Also being able to disable alt for shortcuts to the top bar (file, edit, etc) menu would be handy.